# what are .item, .properties and .screenshot? How to read them?

Tags: talend

When I push my job, which I designed in Talend Studio in GitLab, I saw 3 files (`.item`, `.properties`, and `.screenshot`) per job under the `process` folder.

Questions:

1. What role do the 3 files play?
2. When I try to change an existing job and push to Git, there are some diffs in those 3 files. But those diffs seems cryptic to me. How could I read those files?

For example `.screenshot` files

Before changing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<talendfile:ScreenshotsMap xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:talendfile="platform:/resource/org.talend.model/model/TalendFile.xsd" key="process" value="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBgAAAHxCAIAAABI8JjTAAAv/klEQVR4nO3deXCc9Z3ncdXWztRUJamdqa3a2pl/Zqa2KscmsJVKMpPK1izxEO/.../Pzhyck+Pn5+fn5+fn5+fnDExL8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz8/OEJCX5+fn5+fn5+fn7+8IQEPz8/Pz8/Pz8/P394/x/MYxX37hKydQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/>
```

After changing:

```xml
<talendfile:ScreenshotsMap xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:talendfile="platform:/resource/org.talend.model/model/TalendFile.xsd" key="process" value="iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBgAAAHxCAIAAABI8JjTAABCd0lEQVR4nO3de3Cc5Z3ge9XUztScIjmzU1u1tbPnjzN7TtUkbAJbqSQzKbb2EC/xzvlra+fMJDuZCRdzM2BQnJDrkAEmF2YyTnCCTYQDJDHhEmCDwRiDJtyv5m6DDdiAAVs3y5J1v3XL8Xm6X6nVkuVuPzaS3vfVR/.../PzRIyT4+fn5+fn5+fn5+aNHSPDz8/Pz8/Pz8/PzR4+Q4Ofn5+fn5+fn5+ePHiHBz8/Pz8/Pz8/Pzx89QoKfn5+fn5+fn5+fP3qEBD8/Pz8/Pz8/Pz9/9Pz/DP6n89Dd4IMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot file value is a base64 string that is a snapshot image of the job itself.

So if you change the job, the screenshot changes.

That image can be viewed from Talend Cloud so as to provide any person administering the job an overview of what the job looks like.

It’s literally a screenshot.

As for the other two files, they’re just important files that make up the job itself.

They contain meta data and values that were configured by you or Talend itself.

All are important to the structure, execution and overall workings of the job.